# add a new JSON property using existing property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a file of JSON-serialized data that looks like this:

```
{
    "name":"Store",
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"Store 1",
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"collection 1",
                    "description":"collection 1",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"Products",
                            "description":"Products",
                            "children":[
                                {
                                    "name":"Product 1",
                                    "description":"Product 1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "description":"category 1"
        },
        {
            "name":"Store 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

For objects with a `name` property, I want to add a `title` whose value is the same as the value of the `name` property. Below is what I am trying to convert my JSON to:

```
{
    "name":"Store",
    "title":"Store",
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"Store 1",
            "title":"Store 1",
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"collection 1",
                    "title":"collection 1",
                    "description":"collection 1",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"Products",
                            "title":"Products",
                            "description":"Products",
                            "children":[
                                {
                                    "name":"Product 1",
                                    "title":"Product 1",
                                    "description":"Product 1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "description":"category 1"
        },
        {
            "name":"Store 2",
            "title":"Store 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried? Show us that, and maybe we can tell you where you're going wrong.

Comment: the farthest i could reach is replacing it by JSON.stringify(data).replace(/"name"/g, '"title"'), but i cant find a method or resources on how to duplicate the object.

Comment: 1) you said the daya you have already IS JSON (in a file), so why would you stringify it? 2) never manipulate your data via string operations on the serialized form

Comment: so what should i do in this case? .map it and restructure it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const addTitleRec = (j) => {
  j.title = j.name, j.children && j.children.forEach(addTitleRec);
}

const json = {
  "name": "Store",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Store 1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "collection 1",
        "description": "collection 1",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Products",
          "description": "Products",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Product 1",
            "description": "Product 1"
          }]
        }]
      }],
      "description": "category 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Store 2"
    }
  ]
};

addTitleRec(json);

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

we can use parse the Json using JSON.Parse and use recursion to add title as below to all the children

```
function Recursion(items) {
  items["title"] = items["name"]
  if (items["children"] != undefined) {
    items["children"].forEach(element => {
      element = Recursion(element)
    });
  }
  return items
}



 var text = '{"name":"Store","children":[{"name":"Store 1","children":[{"name":"collection 1","description":"collection 1","children":[{"name":"Products","description":"Products","children":[{"name":"Product 1","description":"Product 1"}]}]}],"description":"category 1"},{"name":"Store 2"}]}';
  var item = JSON.parse(text);
  item = Recursion(item);
```

Comment: +1  In my own fiddling around I used `map` to do the recursion but it all works out the same `transform = function (d) {
 if (d.name) {
   d.title = d.name;
 }
   
 if (d.children) {
   d.children = d.children.map(transform);
 }
  
  return d;
}`